# Connect Silex to MSSQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine, silex

Does anyone know how to connect a Silex based Web Application to a MSSQL DB?

I tried the https://packagist.org/packages/localgod/pdo-service-provider

but don't know which driver I have to use.

Comment: As far as I understand your web server runs under unix? If fo you can use a PDO Sybase's driver which is compatible with MSSQL. I already make it ran with MSSQL2008R on a Redhat.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't over think it, at the end you're just using PDO so check [the PDO's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php) and use the [SQLSRVR driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php).

NOTE: I've never used PDO in Ms SQL, but once installed the driver it should be straight forward to use, from the comments on the SQLSRV:

> As of 12/12/2014, Microsoft has officially released Version 3.1.
>
> Support for 5.5 has 4 drivers php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
>   php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
>
> Note: Version 3.1 now supports PHP 5.5 and requires Microsoft ODBC
>   Driver 11 (or higher)
>
> You can downlod the new driver from
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

So, once enabled you can just use the *sqlsrv* and this should work (or you can skip this provider and use raw PDO: `$c = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=testdb", "UserName", "Password");`)

Edited to give Linux/Unix instructions:

If you are running your PHP code from linux, you just need to use de default ODBC driver (from the docs: The PDO_SQLSRV extension is only compatible with PHP running on Windows. For Linux, see [ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) and » Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux.)

Also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728290/mssql-servers-native-odbc-driver-for-linux-and-php-5-4).

Comment: Yeah thx but I am working on a linux based web server and have to connect to a mssql db...